# Using sd card as part of c:

Tags: partitioning

I have a laptop with only 32Gb internal storage and a 64Gb SD card that I never remove.

The internal drive is almost full even though I keep documents and the like on the external card.

the internal drive (C:) contains Windows 10. I heard about spanned drives but the instructions I found speak of deleting partitions. There's also RAID0 that is similar to Spanned drives but should be faster and then there's symlinking.

Which is the best way to merge the two drives into one volume without losing Windows?

Comment: Spanned drives IIRC are only available in Win 7 & 8.  Have you tried to simply clean up your **C:** drive?

Comment: Yes, I tried running disc cleanup but it freed a very small amount of data.